# Kubuntu 14.04: Font rendering on KDE Issues (Rendering Ubuntu fonts as Debian default)

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, fonts

Kubuntu 14.04 is working fine on my computer but I have recently installed it from my USB Device using other boot managers from which allowed me to boot to USB.

Now after I got to Xscreensaver the font rendering is wrong, looks like Ubuntu font has renderized as Debian default font rendering.

I woke up and found out that the KDE Desktop is entirely fine except for the fonts that the Ubuntu font has rendered as Debian default font rendering.

Login screen is fine though as the login does not use Ubuntu font, It does not have problem with font rendering on TTY.

These are the pictures from what I mean:

[image: Debian-rendering font 1]

[image: Debian-rendering font 2]

[image: Debian-rendering font 3]

[image: Debian-rendering font 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing Ubuntu instead of Kubuntu

Comment: It is the font hinting and so forgive me.